# Call sscanf with multiple strings

Tags: string, matlab, date, matrix, scanf

I want to convert date strings to a numerical matrix and I need to do it with in a very high speed. My input:

```
 dateStrings = [
     '2015 07 09 12 28 18.17641';
     '2015 07 09 12 28 19.17641';
     '2015 07 09 12 28 20.17641']
```

I now want to convert them to numbers using `sscanf`. (The reason being it is very fast). This works fine if dateStrings only contains 1 string, but in this case I have 3 strings. (In reality 50 000+).

```
sscanf(dateStrings, '%d %d %d %d %d %f')
```

Desired output is a matrix looking like:

```
 2015            7            9           12           28       18.176
 2015            7            9           12           28       19.176
 2015            7            9           12           28       20.176
```

Is there any way to make on call to sscanf with multiple strings, or do i have to make a loop?

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem is welcome, as long as it's fast!

---

EDIT: Suever's solution gave me a ton of speed! However, the above stated input is not really true. The actual input looks below. Since you mentioned working with cells actually is quicker, how would you do it using this input? At the moment i convert the input using `cell2mat`, and then replace certain index with spaces to end up with strings like: `'2015 07 09 12 28 18.17641'`.

```
Input is 4x1 cell:

    '2015-11-18T23:31:49.37486 +01:00'
    '2015-11-18T23:31:49.37583 +01:00'
    '2015-11-18T23:31:49.37658 +01:00'
    '2015-11-18T23:31:49.37735 +01:00'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2D character arrays are particularly difficult to manipulate. If you first convert it to a cell using `cellstr` it will be much easier to work with.

```
C = cellstr(dateStrings);
output = sscanf(sprintf('%s ', C{:}), '%f');
output = reshape(output, [], numel(C)).';     %'

%//  2015            7            9           12           28       18.176
%//  2015            7            9           12           28       19.176
%//  2015            7            9           12           28       20.176
```

Or you could use `cellfun`

```
output = cellfun(@(x)sscanf(x, '%f'), C, 'uni', 0);
output = cat(2, output{:}).';
```

You could also use a combination of `str2num` and `strjoin`.

```
output = reshape(str2num(strjoin(C)), [], numel(C)).';
```

Honestly though, looping through your initial data may be the fastest option.

```
output = NaN(size(dateStrings,1), 6);
for k = 1:size(dateStrings, 1);
    output(k,:) = sscanf(dateStrings(k,:), '%f');
end
```

I benchmarked these methods using inputs with various number of rows and got the following results. The first and third look to be the most performant.

[image]

## Update

Since your initial question wasn't an accurate representation of your data at all, you will now need to change your format specifier to `sscanf`. Also you can just pass your input cell array (`C`) *directly* rather than using `cellstr`.

```
sscanf(x, '%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%f +%*d:%*d')
```

So we can apply that to some of the answers above:

```
%// Option #1
fmt = '%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%f +%*d:%*d';
output = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s ', C{:}), fmt), [], numel(C)).';   %'

%// Option #2
output = cellfun(@(x)sscanf(x, fmt), C, 'uni', 0);
output = cat(2, output{:}).';   %'

%// Option #4
output = NaN(numel(C), 6);
for k = 1:numel(C)
    output(k,:) = sscanf(C{k}, fmt);
end
```

Comment: Very nice! Using the first solution sped me up quite a lot. I edited my question, do you have any input on the latter part?

Comment: @Goatcat I have updated the solution. Next time it's beneficial to post the actual data. Especially when it is something that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, epic work! At a first test your solution is like 10 times faster (using option #1). I am ever grateful!

Comment: @Goatcat if an answer solved your problem, do **not** ask another question in the comments or update the question with new requirements. Instead, mark the answer as accepted and ask another question in a separate post.